# Will `npm install -g lodash` add lodash to my package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

If a package is installed as a global node package by npm, will it be added to my project's local package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this will add lodash to the global package.json file, not the current project one.

Comment: didn't know that there was a global `package.json` file. Do you know where this global file is located?